# Customize Dropdown

Tags: angularjs

when i click on **Deploy** button it's upload both environment list, and category list Instead it opening both lists it should open just the environment list, then open the category list once an environment has been selected.

```
<div class="download-options">
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="dropdown" id="download-target-environment-dropdown" ng-show="!comparisonDeployment">
      <label class="control-label">Target Environment:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-target="#"
               value="{{targetEnvironment.alias}}" readonly>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-class="{show: !targetEnvironment}">
        <li ng-repeat="env in environments">
          <a ng-click="setTargetEnvironment(env)">{{env.alias}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="download-data-type-dropdown">
      <label class="control-label">Categorie`enter code here`s:</label>
      <input id="add_a_category" type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
               data-target="#"
               value="Add a category" readonly/>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-class="{show: !type}">
        <li ng-repeat="type in typesInfo" ng-class="{disabled: !hasRootFromType(type)}">
          <a ng-click="setType(type)">{{type.alias}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, provide us your code, current output, desired output, ...

Comment: Hi Pengyy,
there is one "Deploy" button in my HTML page. The behavior of button is-when it click it's open one more form and in form there is two drop down list "Target Environment" and "Categorie"
current behavior is :when i click on Deploy button it's upload both Target Environment, and Categorie
instead of this it should open just the environment list, then open the category list once an environment has been selected.